# COVID-19 - Travelling to the UK with two doses of an un-approved vaccine and one approved booster dose

Tags: uk, covid-19, vaccinations

A family member,  who's not a UK resident or a British national, is planning to come visit me in the UK in January. He's been given two doses of Sputnik and one booster jab of Oxford-AstraZeneca.

Assuming the WHO doesn't approve the Sputnik vaccine before my family member travels, **would he be considered as vaccinated or unvaccinated when entering the UK?**

I cannot find any information around this scenario in the official GOV.UK website: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/countries-with-approved-covid-19-vaccination-programmes-and-proof-of-vaccination

As a side note, he won't be coming from a red list country.

Comment: The website states “you must have proof of full vaccination with a full course of an approved vaccine.” Your family member doesn’t have that.

Answer (score 5):

> Assuming the WHO doesn't approve the Sputnik vaccine before my family member travels, would he be considered as vaccinated or unvaccinated when entering the UK?

Unvaccinated, since Sputnik doesn't count for the UK.